# Comparing two dates as char arrays in C

Tags: c, string, comparison

Bear with my guys this is my second stackoverflow question, please point me in the right direction if I'm doing this wrong

I have two dates as chars.

I print out the dates:

```
printf("%s - %s\n",tmpPtr->date, currentDate);
```

And I have an if statement which is **always** executed

```
if(tmpPtr->date != currentDate) {       // perhaps strcmp(), don't know
  printf("Dates are not equal\n");
}
```

But this cannot be true because these are my results:

```
27/12/2015 - 27/12/2015
Dates are not equal
27/12/2015 - 27/12/2015
Dates are not equal
28/12/2015 - 27/12/2015
Dates are not equal
29/12/2015 - 28/12/2015
Dates are not equal
29/12/2015 - 29/12/2015
Dates are not equal
29/12/2015 - 29/12/2015
Dates are not equal
30/12/2015 - 29/12/2015
Dates are not equal
31/12/2015 - 30/12/2015
Dates are not equal
31/12/2015 - 31/12/2015
Dates are not equal
```

This can't be true because some dates are equal?

Am I comparing the strings correctly? Is it just comparing the memory allocation or something of the sort?

Comment: Did you even *read* the comment in your own code? Did you have a look at the documentation for `strcmp()`?

Comment: To add on what @EOF wrote: Did you try `strcmp` as you considered yourself already? Why did it not work? Why did you not try?

Comment: Yeah I did, I read the documentation. I read this, if Return value < 0 then it indicates str1 is less than str2.

if Return value > 0 then it indicates str2 is less than str1.

if Return value = 0 then it indicates str1 is equal to str2. I made an assumption that it was about the length of the string as I mentioned in the answer @Olaf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to compare strings, use `strcmp()` like this :

```
if (strcmp(tmpPtr->date,currentDate) != 0) {      
    printf("Dates are not equal\n");
}
```

Comment: I thought strcmp was just the number of letters?

Comment: @Blarsssss That's `strlen`. [This character and string function reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) might be helpful.

Comment: @Blarsssss, as the user above said, this is `strlen`, whereas `strcmp` is for string comparison. I am glad it helped, if your problem is resolved I would appreciate it if you accepted my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If dates are in the same format which seems to be the case, then use `strcmp`. Otherwise parse them and compare year, month and date of one string to corresponding fields of the other.